# React: invalid hook call onSubmit function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, submit

I'm using `react-hook-form` and little state machine to store the values of the form.

I use it for a survey with 2 choices, the user click on an answer, then click on the "next" button (submit type) to go on the next question, on so on.

The issue is when I want to use little state machine on the submit function I get an error:

> invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component...

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

`onSubmit` code:

```
export const onSubmit = (data) => {
  const { actions, state } = useStateMachine({ updateAction });

  actions.updateAction({
    ...data,
    step: state.surveyInfos.step + 1,
    tags: [...state.surveyInfos.tags, data.tags],
    Q1Score: state.surveyInfos.Q1Score + data.quotationResponse,
    Q2Score: state.surveyInfos.Q2Score + data.quotationResponse,
  });
};
```

My form :

```
 interface IFormProfileProps {
  data: IHomeProps;
  sizeQuestionnaire: number;
}

export const FormProfile = ({ data, sizeQuestionnaire }: IFormProfileProps) => {
  const form = useForm({ shouldUnregister: true });
  const { state } = useStateMachine();
  const [valueChoice, setValueChoice] = useState(state[data?.questionCode]);
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
    >
      <FormControl component="fieldset">
        <FormLabel component="legend">
        <Typography variant="h4"> {data.data[0]?.questionText} </Typography> 
        </FormLabel>
        <Box display="flex" flex={1} gap={5}>
          {data?.data?.map((value, index) => {
            return (
              <Box key={index} display="flex" flex={1}>
                <input
                  {...form.register(data?.questionCode, { required: true })}
                  type="radio"
                  checked={valueChoice === `response-card-${value?.questionCode}-${index}`}
                  value={`${value.subSurvey}-${value.tag}-${index}`}
                  onChange={() => setValueChoice(`response-card-${value?.questionCode}-${index}`)}
                  id={`field-${data?.questionCode}-${index}`}
                />
                <label
                  htmlFor={`field-${data?.questionCode}-${index}`}
                  key={index}
                >
                  <ResponseCard
                    borderColor={
                      valueChoice === `response-card-${value?.questionCode}-${index}`
                        ? grey.light
                        : state[data?.questionCode] === `response-card-${value?.questionCode}-${index}`
                        ? grey.light
                        : grey.extraLight
                    }
                    responseTitle={value?.answerTitle}
                    responseText={value?.answerText}
                  />
                </label>
              </Box>
            );
          })}
        </Box>
      </FormControl>
      <ActionButtons sizeQuestionnaire={sizeQuestionnaire} />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hooks are designed to be called in React functional components only. Cannot call it from regular JS functions. See [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are using: `useStateMachine` inside the `onSubmit` function. That is why it is telling you that you are using it outside of a component.

**SOLUTION 1**

Use it inside the component where you are using the `onSubmit`. And also you should define that `onSubmit` there:

```js
export const FormProfile = ({ data, sizeQuestionnaire }: IFormProfileProps) => {
  const form = useForm({ shouldUnregister: true });
  const { state } = useStateMachine();
  const [valueChoice, setValueChoice] = useState(state[data?.questionCode]);

  /* ------------- PART IN QUESTIONS */

  const { actions, state } = useStateMachine({ updateAction });
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    actions.updateAction({
      ...data,
      step: state.surveyInfos.step + 1,
      tags: [...state.surveyInfos.tags, data.tags],
      Q1Score: state.surveyInfos.Q1Score + data.quotationResponse,
      Q2Score: state.surveyInfos.Q2Score + data.quotationResponse,
    });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <FormControl component="fieldset">
        <FormLabel component="legend">
          <Typography variant="h4"> {data.data[0]?.questionText} </Typography>
        </FormLabel>
        <Box display="flex" flex={1} gap={5}>
          {data?.data?.map((value, index) => {
            return (
              <Box key={index} display="flex" flex={1}>
                <input
                  {...form.register(data?.questionCode, { required: true })}
                  type="radio"
                  checked={valueChoice === `response-card-${value?.questionCode}-${index}`}
                  value={`${value.subSurvey}-${value.tag}-${index}`}
                  onChange={() => setValueChoice(`response-card-${value?.questionCode}-${index}`)}
                  id={`field-${data?.questionCode}-${index}`}
                />
                <label htmlFor={`field-${data?.questionCode}-${index}`} key={index}>
                  <ResponseCard
                    borderColor={
                      valueChoice === `response-card-${value?.questionCode}-${index}`
                        ? grey.light
                        : state[data?.questionCode] === `response-card-${value?.questionCode}-${index}`
                        ? grey.light
                        : grey.extraLight
                    }
                    responseTitle={value?.answerTitle}
                    responseText={value?.answerText}
                  />
                </label>
              </Box>
            );
          })}
        </Box>
      </FormControl>
      <ActionButtons sizeQuestionnaire={sizeQuestionnaire} />
    </form>
  );
};
```

---

**SOLUTION 2**

If you want to make that code reusable, you can create a hook, ex `useOnSubmit`, and than use that hook inside the `FormProfile` component:

```js
export function useOnSubmit() {
  const { actions, state } = useStateMachine({ updateAction });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    actions.updateAction({
      ...data,
      step: state.surveyInfos.step + 1,
      tags: [...state.surveyInfos.tags, data.tags],
      Q1Score: state.surveyInfos.Q1Score + data.quotationResponse,
      Q2Score: state.surveyInfos.Q2Score + data.quotationResponse,
    });
  };

  return onSubmit;
}
```

Then, use it as such:

```js
export const FormProfile = ({ data, sizeQuestionnaire }: IFormProfileProps) => {
  const form = useForm({ shouldUnregister: true });
  const { state } = useStateMachine();
  const [valueChoice, setValueChoice] = useState(state[data?.questionCode]);

  /* ------------- PART IN QUESTIONS */

  const onSubmit = useOnSubmit();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      ...
    </form>
  );
};
```